# Pushmode, popMode example

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to learn ANTLR and came across pushMode and popMode lexical modes.

I went through lots of material on google around this (including mega tutorial), but failed to get working of pushMode and popMode.

My Lexer grammar is

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;
OPEN_QUOTE: '"' -> pushMode(STRING);
TEXT: [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUMBER: [0-9]+;
mode STRING;
CLOSE_QUOTE: '"' -> popMode;
WORD: [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUM: [0-9]+;
```

My Parser is

```
parser grammar MyParser;
options {tokenVocab=MyLexer;}
test: sentence string ;
sentence: (TEXT|NUMBER)+;
string: OPEN_QUOTE (WORD NUM) CLOSE_QUOTE;
```

And my input is

```
this is sentence 
"this is string"
```

I am not convinced with thing that for first input I am using lexers which are defined in pushMode and mode. While for second statement I am using lexers which are out side pushMode and popMode.
I was under impression that this should be in reverse way as below

```
parser grammar MyParser;
options {tokenVocab=MyLexer;}
test: sentence string ;
sentence: (WORD|NUM)+;
string: OPEN_QUOTE (TEXT|NUMBER) CLOSE_QUOTE;
```

Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not handling whitespace inside you lexer rules.

Common rule is:

```
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

You don't want to skip whitespace within a string however.  In fact you really don't want to skip anything.

try:

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;
OPEN_QUOTE: '"' -> pushMode(STRING);
TEXT: [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUMBER: [0-9]+;
mode STRING;
CLOSE_QUOTE: '"' -> popMode;
STRING_CONTENT: ~["]* ;
```

The `~["]*`  says to match anything that is not a `"`.

in your Lexer rules, `OPEN_QUOTE`, `TEXT`, and `NUMBER` are all rules in the default, or top-level Lexer mode.  When you encounter the `OPEN_QUOTE` you "push" the Lexer into the `STRING` mode, where it will only look at the `CLOSE_QUOTE`, `WORD`, and `NUMBER` rules. (Of course, the `popMode` on `CLOSE_QUOTE` pops the lexer back into the top-level default Lexer mode.  You should consider using the `grun` tool to dump out the token stream (`-tokens` option), as it might make this a bit more clear.

Note: generally `STRING` Lexer rules are more involved than this (suggest looking at `STRING` rules in other grammars).  But, this should handle your test to understand Lexer modes.

Comment: Thanks for reply and solution. Can I request you to help me with working of pushMode and popMode? I didnt get any satisfactory explanation for same.

Comment: Why cant i use "sentence" in place of "STRING_CONTENTS" for "string" parser?

Comment: ANTLR processes all characters through Lexer rules to produce a token stream.  Parser rules, then act on the token stream.   Lexer rules cannot contain parser rules, because parsing is done on the stream of tokens produced by the Lexer (Lexing is complete, before parser rules are involved)

Comment: Thanks Mike. Please allow me to rephrase my question. Why can't I use "(WORD|NUM)+" in place of "STRING_CONTENTS"? Apologies that I am asking too many things, i am just trying to clear my understanding.

Comment: `(WORD|NUM)+` doesn’t account for whitespace (spaces, new lines, etc.), nor does it account for non-alphanumeric characters.   For your specific example, it’s important that those two rules don’t include the space character.  If you `skip the whitespace (with the `WS` rule I suggested (which would have to be matched with another `WS2` rule in the STRING mode, since WSJ is in the top-level, default mode)), you’d have a parse tree of `WORD` and ‘NUM` tokens that would not account for the spaces.  It should be obvious if you use grunt tool to print the token stream and the GUI parse tree.

Comment: Thanks Mike for clarification and appreciate your expertise in Antlr. Do you have any blog or page where everything mentioned about lexer commands? :)